# How to get channel description?

Tags: discord, discord.js

I'm using Discord.js V14 and I can't find a way to get the channel description. I already have the channel, I just need to get the description for a channel info command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use .topic for this. For more information, see https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/main/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=topic